# Is there any alternative to using if walls instead of something else in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, hashmap

I'm doing some C++ and my app accepts subcommands, for example `./my_app test 123`.

I'm semi-new to C++ and I can't find anything on the internet so I don't know haha.

For example in python I'd do:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def test(num):
    print(f"Test {num}")

subcommands = {"test": test}

subcommands[sys.argv[1](sys.argv[2])
```

any C++ eq to this? if so, should I use it or stick to if-else_if-else?

Comment: I do not know what an if wall is. Any relationship with Larry Wall?

Comment: @user4581301 if statement wall = a bunch of if/else if/else statements, example: https://pastebin.com/4nJ6QmXr

Comment: Stick with `if` at first. If you really want to, try `std::map`, `std::string` and `std::function`, but they come with performance penalty.

Comment: In C++, unlike Python, there isn't built-in support for mapping a string to a function.   If you want such a capability, you need to implement it  (e.g. a data structure and/or code to explicitly map a string to a function pointer, in order to call that function - and that needs to be tailored for the application).   The difference is for various reasons, such as Python being an interpreted language while C++ is not.

Comment: @Ari157 Thank you. Good to know. I've always called them if ladders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)/[`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

void test(const std::string &value) {
    std::cout << "Test " << value << std::endl;
}

using cmdFuncType = void(*)(const std::string &);

const std::map<std::string, cmdFuncType> subcommands = {
    {"test": &test}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "usage: program command value" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    auto iter = subcommands.find(argv[1]);
    if (iter == subcommands.end()) {
        std::cerr << "unknown command: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    iter->second(argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tend to go `std::function<void(std::string&)>` rather than pulling out the `void(*)(const std::string &`. Is there an advantage to using `cmdFuncType` defined like this?

Comment: @Martin York template_instantiate_undefined: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::function<void>'

Comment: @Ari157 did you add `#include <functional>` to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: @MartinYork `std::function` is good if you want to use lambdas for the entries, or mix lambdas/functors/functions together. But if all of the entries are going to be plain functions, the overhead of `std::function` is a bit overkill.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau i did, but your solution works, like it only breaks when i use pure std::function<void(std::string&)>

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void test(int num) {
    std::cout << "Test " << num << "\n";
}

std::map<std::string, std::function<void(int)>> subcommands = {
    {"test", test}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    subcommands[argv[1]](std::atoi(argv[2]));
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault :(

Comment: @Ari157 I am assuming the user puts in valid values. It's an MVP.

Comment: If you add error checking. Then it basically looks like Remy's above. Will leave here simply because this uses `std::function<void(int)>` rather than `void(*)(int)` as an alternative.